# Value shows in browser console but not in my terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I'm trying to get the text (not the value) of  of an HTML element using `node.js`. Note that I am not allowed to change the value of options.

**index.html**

```
<select id=agee class="" name="age" onchange="myNewFunction();">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option id=17 value="no">17 or less</option>
    <option id=18 value="99">18 years old</option>
    <option id=19 value="105">19 years old</option>
    <script src="fetch.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</select>
```

**fetch.js**

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const $ = require('jquery')(new jsdom.JSDOM().window);

module.exports.myNewFunction = myNewFunction;

function myNewFunction() {
  var selectedText = $( "#agee option:selected" ).text();
  console.log("your selected text is" + selectedText);

  return selectedText ;
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");
const date = require(__dirname + "/public/fetch.js")
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
$ = require('jquery')(new jsdom.JSDOM().window);

app.use(
    bodyParser.json(),
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get("/",function(req,res){

res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");

})

app.post("/", function(req,res){
var age = date.myNewFunction();
console.log("this is my age : " + age);})
```

The problem here is that my terminal doesn't show me the value of age, the console prints only "this is my age", but in the same time, the web console shows me the value of selectedText. I don't understand my error or how this is even possible ?

I am a beginner so thanks so much for your time and help !

Comment: Can you rename `$=` to `const $ = ...` Browser runs in non-strict mode where as node runs in strict mode

Comment: @Rajesh I just corrected thanks, but it still not work, can you be a bit more specific please ?

Comment: Don't you need a `type="module"` attribute on the `<script src="fetch.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: @mplungjan when I do, I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: myNewFunction is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ((index):26:71)

Comment: @mplungjan Even if I comment it out, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Express requires middleware to view the body of the request, and you have the `body-parser` installed which is the middleware for viewing the body of a request, but you aren't telling Express to use it.

You can fix that by simply adding

```js
app.use(
    bodyParser.json(),
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working :(